# Problem with parsing XML to DataGrid in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, mxml

Here I i'm trying to parsing a XML in like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<spearkerslist>
    <speakers langid="afb" countryid="SA">200000</speakers>
    <speakers langid="acw" countryid="SA">6000000</speakers>
    <speakers langid="ars" countryid="SA">8000000</speakers>
    <speakers langid="arb" countryid="SA">206000000</speakers>
</spearkerslist>
```

By this code I'm able to parse parameters langid and countryid, but I'm not able to parse the actual values 200000, 6000000,... into the data grid. Is there a way to access this with out changing the generated XML.

```
<mx:Script>
[Bindable]
private var languagelist:XML = new XML();
</mx:Script>

<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{languagelist.speakers}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="populationCol" dataField="speakers" headerText="Speakers" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="countryID" dataField="@countryid" headerText="Country Id" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="LangID" dataField="@langid" headerText="Language Id" />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without `dataField`:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn id="populationCol" headerText="Speakers" />
```

If this doesn't work, use [labelFunction](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#labelFunction)

```
<mx:DataGridColumn id="populationCol" headerText="Speakers" 
     labelFunction="dgLabelFunction"/>
```

Define it as:

```
public function dgLabelFunction(item:Object, col:DataGridColumn):String
{
    return item.text().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a FYI for anyone facing similar problem.You can also specify dataField="*" to achieve the same result.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn id="populationCol" headerText="Speakers" dataField="*"/>
```